# Emmet in sublime: Nesting operators don't work while other operators work excellent

Tags: nested, operators, sublimetext3, emmet

`div.test` gives me `<div class="test"></div>` but 
`div>div`  gives me `div><div></div>`. 
It is sublime3. It worked before. A long time. Then I installed and removed a lot of packages. In some moment nesting operators stopped working. Maybe somebody faced it.

Comment: I guess you should log this as an issue at https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason. I didn't notice that in command log (sublime.log_commands(True)) executed another command: `insert_best_completion` instead of emmet's command `expand_abbreviation_by_tab`.

Emmet failed to start. Because of strange package control loader: `0_package_control_loader.sublime-package` (in Installed Packages directory). 
Found solution on https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-emmet-not-working-in-3124/23122

- exit st3
- rename 0_package_control_loader.sublime-package to
  0_package_control_loader.sublime-package.bak (or move file for
  backup) (path for ubuntu:
  /home/*username*/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed
  Packages/0_package_control_loader.sublime-package)
- start st3 (file > 0_package_control_loader.sublime-package is
  automatically created -> emmet work)